# Excel Addin Creation for only one file

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have created a VS Addin Project where I have written code to add a custom menu with some menu items in C#. By this I got a VSTO deployment file. Now I open a random excel file and add this addin or vsto manually by Excel Options-> Addins->Manage (Com Addins) -> Go and Added the addin. My isuue is that the addin gets added in all files alongwith the file in which I added. I want that the user view this addin menu for the file for which s/he added manually. Our approach is free to ask user to go thru some special steps to follow or I can write C# code also for achieving this. Also we cannot do this by identifying the file name as the name and location of file may change. Please suggest any workaround as I am totally stuck on this issue.

Comment: Add-ins are always installed at the application-level, not per file. You'll either have to do something clever with the VSTO, such as Arshad suggested, or you should ditch VSTO and either use macros or embed an ActiveX object in the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you create a toggle button to show/add and hide/remove your custom task pane. 
follow the instruction at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942846.aspx 
[msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/hh128771](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/hh128771)

---

create a excel addin using visual studio.
add a user control, a ribbon (visual) using right click -> add new 
user control will be your takspane.
add a toggle button in the ribbon.

then, in the `ThisAddIn.cs` add following lines:

```
 private UserControl1 myUserControl1;
        private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            myUserControl1 = new UserControl1();
            myCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl1, "My Task Pane");

        }
        public void toggle(bool b)
        {
            myCustomTaskPane.Visible = b;
        }
```

after that,  in the `Ribbon1.cs` add the following code :

```
 private void toggleButton1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.toggle(toggleButton1.Checked);
        }
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: But this will also add a task pane in all excels ? I want that any functionality I am adding in my addin project should be visible on one file only.

Comment: on start... hide the taskpane.. on button click -> add to the current document. this will add to current document. if not then you can share your code

Comment: If I create button that will also be visible in all excels. I also have read here-> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx#LoadBehavior that the load behavior of addins can be set as 0 to achieve the funcationality I need. But how can I set this in C# code.

Comment: that's about the setup, launching the application. set it to 3. set you addin (usercontol) not visible. but, toggle button will come in ribbon.

Comment: Actually I cant have anything extra to be visible on all excels.

Comment: if you have got the solution from this answer, don't  forget to mark it.

Comment: Arshad, its displaying a toggle button. I have found the resolution based on LoadBehavior=0